# Transactional test wont rollback after completion

Tags: mysql, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, transactional

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with JUnit4 and MySQL 5.7.

After executing a test where JDBCTemplate inserts a record in a database, this newly inserted record remains in the customers table. I tried different variations (for example, moving @Transactional and @Rollback to a method) but it was all the same.

Code for the test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class TestJDBCTemplate
    {

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Test
    public void testInsert()
        {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name) VALUES (\"Jeff\", \"Johnson\")");

        // This condition is irrelevant
        assertEquals(1, 1);
        }

    }
```

Code for the ContextCOnfiguration:
    package com.example.demo.test;

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class TestConfig
    {

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource()
        {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
        }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
        {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        }

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
        {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        return jdbcTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Customers table was created using this line of code:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE customers(" + "id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))");
```

Could you please tell me what is preventing the rollback after test completion?

Comment: What do you want to rollback exactly? the insertion?

Comment: Yes, in this example it is insertion (but it could be any other change to the table).

Comment: You are using MySQL so make sure you are using InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables.

Comment: M. Deinum, that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thank @M.Deinum, can you please add the comment as an anwer so other people can see the solution? And I kindly request from Cybex to mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when using MySQL and the fact that `@Rollback` (or rolling back a transaction in general) isn't working this is because the usage of the wrong table type in MySQL.

Newer versions use the [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) storage engine by default however older versions (or using the wrong dialect for your JPA provider) will use the [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) storage engine.

The InnoDB engine has support for transactions whereas the MyISAM type doesn't. Hence doing a rollback on a MyISAM based table won't do anything.

To fix either set the default storage engine in MySQL to InnoDB or when creating the table specify the storage engine to use.

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
  id SERIAL, 
  first_name VARCHAR(255), 
  last_name VARCHAR(255))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Yes, in my case Customers table was created by JDBCTemplate.execute and turned out to be using MyISAM engine. Everything works just fine after manually changing it to InnoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

1. Add a new applciation profile using

> spring.profile.active=test,DEV..ETC

[Checkout offical Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

2. In the test profile,use new db credentials for testing and  use the following hibernate property

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=**create-drop**

This will generate create the tables for you and after finish, it will drop the tables.

**UPDATE**

Even you you are not using JPA, you can use the JPA configuration with **JDPCTemplate**
If you want to keep existing data, you can still use

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=**create**

The datasource config in application properties even with JPA allows you to use jdpc template 
just like the following

```
 @Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: I'm not using JPA in this example. It's only JDBC. Also, dropping the table won't work cause I would like to keep the existing information in the tables.

Comment: I tried adding spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create to application.properties but it didn't work.

Comment: @Cybex can you please provide the exact error you face?

Comment: The problem was that the record remained in the database after @Transaction test execution. Changes weren't rolled back. But as M. Deinum suggested, the problem was with ISAM tables being used in MySQL  instead of InnoDB.